# TypeScript error with self-relation generic in base service extending union type service

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm encountering an issue with TypeScript involving a self-relation generic in my base service, specifically BaseSelfRelationService. When I attempt to extend this service from another service representing a union type, BaseAssetService, I'm facing an error:

```
Type 'TReturn' does not satisfy the constraint '{ id?: number | undefined; parent?: TReturn | undefined; }'.
  Type 'PhysicalAsset | VirtualAsset' is not assignable to type '{ id?: number | undefined; parent?: TReturn | undefined; }'.
    Type 'PhysicalAsset' is not assignable to type '{ id?: number | undefined; parent?: TReturn | undefined; }'.
      Types of property 'parent' are incompatible.
        Type 'PhysicalAsset | undefined' is not assignable to type 'TReturn | undefined'.
          Type 'PhysicalAsset' is not assignable to type 'TReturn'.
            'PhysicalAsset' is assignable to the constraint of type 'TReturn', but 'TReturn' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'PhysicalAsset | VirtualAsset'.(2344)
```

Here's the minimal reproducible code:

```
class PhysicalAsset {
  id?: number;
  code?: number;
  parent?: PhysicalAsset;
}

class VirtualAsset {
  id?: number;
  name?: string;
  parent?: VirtualAsset;
}

class BaseSelfRelationService<TReturn extends {id?: number; parent?: TReturn} > {
  obj?: TReturn;
}

//Error on this line
class BaseAssetService<TReturn extends PhysicalAsset | VirtualAsset> extends BaseSelfRelationService<TReturn> {}

class PhysicalAssetService extends BaseAssetService<PhysicalAsset> {}

class VirtualAssetAssetService extends BaseAssetService<VirtualAsset> {}
```

I'm seeking assistance in understanding and resolving this error. I would appreciate any help on this. Thank you!

Comment: `TReturn extends PhysicalAsset | VirtualAsset` doesn't mean `TReturn extends {id?: number; parent?: TReturn}`. You can have something like `Foo` as in [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mbrvBm) which extends both `PhysicalAsset` and `VirtualAsset` but whose recursive behavior is more complext than `{parent?: Foo}`.  As for resolving it, why not just use the same constraint in both places, or a combination of them? Something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mAa8Qm) works. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?